# Getting the element that relates to another xpath query

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home")
assert "SEEK" in driver.title

location = WebDriverWait(driver, 25).until(
    ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'location:"
                                                     " Melbourne')]")))

for loc in location:
    print(loc.text)
    job = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span/h1/a").text
    print(job)


driver.close()
```

So I have loc.text to find a specific string within an HTML Document (Located [Here)](https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home)

What I'm trying to do, and have been trying to do for a while now, is:
if the location matches (e.g Melbourne) then take the data from the href link (Both Text and Href) and put it under the location.

```
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But I have issues when running elements hence the reason I'm using element (Can't get it to go from Selenium code to text, it showing all 20 links, unable to specifically show which ones I need, etc etc)

After ages, learning `XPATH` functionality... I'm now stuck on this and countless google searches, and StackOverflow links later, I'm more frustrated than I'd like to be.

What's the easy solution here that I'm missing?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Fix the formatting. Also what is `location`?

Answer (score 1):

To get location `Melbourne` and `Job header` you need to induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following xpath to get parent list and then iterate the loop to check if location `Melbourne` then print the `Job header`

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.seek.com.au/jobs?where=Work%20from%20home")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-automation='searchResults']//article")))

for ele in elements:
    if "Melbourne" in ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='Eadjc1o' and contains(.,'location')]").text:
        print(ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='Eadjc1o' and contains(.,'location')]").text)
        print(ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1/a").text)
        print("======================================")
```

**Console Output:**

```
location: Melbourne
Administration Manager (Part time / Virtual office / Work from home)
======================================
location: Melbourne
Customer Care Consultant - Work From Home
======================================
location: Melbourne
Occupation Coordinator
======================================
location: Melbourne
Planner
======================================
location: Melbourne
Part Time - Customer Contact Officer
======================================
location: Melbourne
Administration Assistant - Dispute Resolution (part time)
======================================
```